# Which wings give the most horizontal distence?

Tags: terraria

I've been looking at some of the new wings added to Terraria in 1.3, and the wiki [clearly shows the height that can be reached with each set](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/terraria.gamepedia.com/0/07/Terraria_Jump_Height_Comparison_Infographic.png). However the stats show that they have different "hover times" and "flight speeds".

My question is: Do the highest flying wings ([Solar Wings](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings)) actually travel the furthest horizontally? If not, which wings (or equivalent flying equipment) do?

(I'm including travelling in the direction while ascending as well as gliding)

Comment: not sure if this helps, because its not a wing set really, but the hoverboard seems to have the fastest horizontal speed to me (using the "hover" move, then shooting sideways). travelling at a low altitude using this method has given me the fastest horizontal travel speed, IMO. the speed may outweigh the shorter distance that it covers compared to wings, if thats what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm thinking on crafting Solar and Vortex, seems to me that those are the ones that could give most horizontal distance. In any case you could use an UFO mount which goes fast enough and frees one accessory slot (the wings) or two, if you like to walk fast too (the boots).

Comment: As soon at the world editor is updated and I can set up a proper test (I got bored of trying to level out a world to work well for distance testing, even using the mining drill mount) I'll see if I can do some proper tests.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [wing types](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings#Types) chart on the wiki, the Solar Wings should provide the greatest horizontal travel distance.

Horizontal Travel Distance can be represented by the following equation:

Horizontal Travel Distance = (Flight Time + Glide Time) * Horizontal Movement speed

Where Glide Time = Height / Glide Fall-Speed

and

Horizontal Movement Speed = Base Horizontal Movement Speed + Horizontal Movement Speed Bonus (we'll call this HFSB).

Glide Fall speed is constant (I tested this below and found it to be ~12 blocks/sec) as is [Base Horizontal Movement Speed (11.36 blocks/sec)](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Speed#Horizontal_movement)

The Solar Wings have the greatest values for both Height and HFSB, and are only 2nd to the Stardust Wings in Flight Time (3.33sec). The Stardust Wings only have a Height of 110 and a HFSB of 83%, so the extra distance gained by their 11% increase in Flight Time is lost by their dramatically lower Height (thus Glide Time) and their low HFSB.

I'll provide an illustrative example. We can get an idea of horizontal travel distance from the wing's specific stats of Time(sec), Height(tiles), and HFSB.

The Solar Wings have 3.0 seconds of Flight Time, 167 blocks of Height, and 200% HFSB.

**200% HFSB** means that we're moving at 3x normal horizontal speed, so 11.36 * 3 = **34.08 blocks/sec**. In the 3 seconds of flight time we travel **102.24 blocks**.

Now, the main distance actually comes from the glide after the wings Flight Time has run out. I was unable to find a number for glide descent speed on the wiki so I went and tested myself to get a reasonable number. My testing (with Fishron Wings) indicated a gliding fall-speed of **~12 blocks/sec**. Using 12 blocks/sec as the glide fall-speed: 167 blocks / ~12 blocks/sec ≈ **13.9 seconds of glide time**. The horizontal distance we can travel during the glide is then: 13.9 seconds * 34.08 blocks/sec = **473.71 blocks.**

Putting this all together, 102.24 blocks + 473.71 blocks = **575.95 blocks** of horizontal travel distance. For comparison, the Fishron Wings with 3sec, 143 blocks, and 167 HFSB yield a horizontal travel distance of **452.44 blocks** while the Stardust Wings with 3.33sec, 110 blocks, 83% HFSB yield only **259.79 blocks**.

EDIT:
I haven't had a chance to try them yet, but the Stardust Wings have notes "Hovering Speed boosted to +150%" and "x2 duration". I'm not sure what these mean exactly -- further testing is required.

Answer (score -1):

The solar wing can go the same horizontally as they can vertical

Comment: That.... seems unlikely. I'm currently using Fishron wings and they travel significantly further horizontally than vertically. Do you have any evidence of this?